# Auto enter input field - storing the data in a div ( counting,dumping values - send to database)

Tags: javascript

I have been writing a small function that has an input box text (only allows 24 numbers) and after typing the 24 numbers the value would be stored into `<div><span>value from input</span></div>`

I would like later on to use jQuery to make some fade in effects.

My question is how to recreate this current script to store the data in a `span` and not create a new `input` each time?

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KZtB/12/)

Could you tell me how to count the values and how to var_dump them? Because later I wan't do make a database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for storing the 24 character in the span.

```
$('.fieldclass').on('keyup', function(){
    if ($(this).val().length == 24) {
        $('span').text($(this).val()); // Update span to the value.
    }
});
```

Or if you want to update the span every time the user pressed a key.

```
$('.fieldclass').on('keyup', function(){
    $('span').text($(this).val()); // Update span to the value.
});
```

Comment: Possibly, could you implement it on the jsFiddle? Seems like I cant place it properly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5KZtB/15/ ok tell me now how could I make a fade effect on that?

Comment: Wonderful Jimmie :) If you would try somehow to create a counter and a value dump ( i want add them later to database ) would be awsome

Comment: A counter of rows or characters in the input?

Comment: Yes, row 24 now gives an alert when a new value is added: http://jsfiddle.net/5KZtB/18/ You can write this out in any div you want. We are almost about to go offtopic now I am afraid.

Comment: Just place it in div for me:) I will update the topic so it doesn't go off. Jimmie what about remove option?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML:

```
<form>
    <span class="input-component"><input type="text"/><a href=#></a></span>
 </form>
<br><br>
<div id="numcontainer">
    <br>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$('form .input-component input').on("propertychange keyup input paste", addInput);

function addInput() {
  var remainingChars = $(this).val().length;
  if (remainingChars == 24) {

    var $newNumSpan = $('<span class="containernum">');
    $newNumSpan.text( $(this).val() );

    $('#numcontainer').append($newNumSpan); // <span class="containernum">1234...</span>
    $('#numcontainer').append('<a class="js-delete" href="#">[X]</a>');
    $('#numcontainer').append('<br>');

    $(this).val(''); // does empty the text input

    values.push($(this).val());
    console.log(values);
  }
}
```

And you should also attach this handler to the `#numcontainer` DOM node in order to delete a "number entry" when clicking an associated [X] link:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var values = [];

    $('#numcontainer').on('click', 'a.js-delete', function(e) {
      $(this).prev().remove(); // the <span>
      $(this).next().remove(); // the <br>
      $(this).remove(); // the <a> itself
    });
    // ...
```

Comment: Wonderful check this http://jsfiddle.net/5KZtB/13/ it pastes it inlane should be a <br> or something.

Comment: Change all your `<span class="containernum">` for `<div class="containernum">` (in JS and HTML)

Comment: I simply added a br value works now. Can u do the [X] option? it got lost

Comment: Not working http://jsfiddle.net/5KZtB/20/ take a look. Also check why It doesn't display the counter

Comment: There was a typo in `addInput`: `<a class="js-delete href=#>[X]</a><br>` (`class` attribute is not closed, not valid HTML), when it should be `<a class="js-delete" href="#">[X]</a><br>`. I uptdated my answer.

Comment: Great job. What about dumping the values? I wan't later send them to database?

Comment: This is a complete other story.. I recommend you to try something on your own and to post here (I mean posting a new question...) when/if you face any problem. Please consider accepting my answer if it did help you.

Comment: Man, this is lame "unupvoted". Anyway, good luck. Let's be constructive here: I really recommend you to take the courses at codecademy.com. There are fun, very useful and free! Begin with the Javascript courses. Cheers.

Comment: Help me to solve it and U get a upvote on all proper comments that helped fixing it.